# Phonegap.js is not found

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a problem with my Phonegap application. I got a 404 error on phonegap.js
I understand that the compiler (I'm using Phonegap build) will replace the src of my phonegap.js by the real path but I don't get that.

It's weird because I have all the other scripts loaded but not this one.

This screenshot is from Safari, debugging my application launched on my iPad to give you more details.

I'm using Phonegap 3.1.0 with an iPad Retina 64 bits with iOS 7.0.

Edit: I can't use Phonegap 3.4.0, Phonegap build is still not supporting it.

[image]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Strange, phonegap.js should be copied at the root of the project at build time. Have you tried with other version of phonegap build (I believe 3.2 should be available). You could also try to use cordova.js instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys but the problem wasn't related to Phonegap. I copied  from our desktop version and that created the problem. And as I wrote in my comment, the screenshot is from Safari debugger for my iPad, not from a browser tab.

Answer (score 1):

Think of phonegap.js as the runtime. It only exists when your app is running on a device.

If you are previewing your app on a local web server, you will get 404 because the local runtime is not your device (its your laptop).

To solve this, developers have invented tools like PhoneGap emulate (http://emulate.phonegap.com/) where you can use an emulator to 'mock' certain behaviors in your local runtime that would occur on a device.

Comment: Hi Adam,
the screenshot that I posted is from my iPad application not from a browser. You can see on the right panel that the index.html is not coming from a server but from /var/mobile/Applications/[id]/Governorhub.app/www/index.html

Comment: Thanks anyway for the emulator, I'll have a look at it.